# Using Composer with local dependencies

Tags: php, composer-php

I know Composer because of Symfony2 but now I would like to use it as a standalone part. I followed the instructions that its documentation said but don't know how to set a local library as a dependency, how to load it?

In other words, how to load a local repository using Composer instead of referencing a remote one?

Answer (score 2):

I've just found the solution! I did everything fine but misstyped the namespace of the dependency I wanted to autoload. So the answer to this question is

1. I installed composer: `curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php`
2. Created a file `composer.json` than put the following content into it:

   ```
   {
       "autoload": {
           "psr-0": {
               "MyNamespace":"src/"
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. run: `php composer.phar install`
4. include into the index.php `../vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: It's only autoloader but you were asking about local dependency? I though you were asking about something like http://marekkalnik.tumblr.com/post/22929686367/composer-installing-package-from-local-git-repository

Comment: Yes, that's correct! Could you write it into an answer and I'll accept it!